# Is there any way to make text float around image only on mobile?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
p {
  margin: 0 0 1em
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  margin: 5%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Are there any ways to make this text go around the image while I minimize browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `flex`. Just use `float` for an image.
**UPDATED**

```css
p {
  margin: 0 0 1em
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  margin: 5%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 
}
/*this will start the rule on screens less then 768px */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.box {display: block;}
img {float: left;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem olor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, i know i could use float. But i want these images to stay like they are. But for example if you are visiting the website on your phone, i want them to go around... so Im using flex to position text in the center while you are on computer

Comment: Updated the answer. Now it will work only on screens less then 768 px width

Comment: Thank you very much! <3

Answer (score 0):

Use `float` and forget about all those `flex` settings:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.box img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem </p>
  </div>
</div>
```